# Overriding the java equals() method - not working?

Tags: java, equals, overriding

I ran into an interesting (and very frustrating) issue with the `equals()` method today which caused what I thought to be a well tested class to crash and cause a bug that took me a very long time to track down.

Just for completeness, I wasn't using an IDE or debugger - just good old fashioned text editor and System.out's. Time was very limited and it was a school project.

Anyhow -

I was developing a basic shopping cart which could contain an *`ArrayList` of `Book` objects*. In order to implement the `addBook()`, `removeBook()`, and `hasBook()` methods of the Cart, I wanted to check if the `Book` already existed in the `Cart`. So off I go -

```
public boolean equals(Book b) {
    ... // More code here - null checks
    if (b.getID() == this.getID()) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

All works fine in testing. I create 6 objects and fill them with data. Do many adds, removes, has() operations on the `Cart` and everything works fine. I read that you can *either have `equals(TYPE var)` or `equals(Object o) { (CAST) var }`* but assumed that since it was working, it didn't matter too much.

Then I ran into a problem - I needed to create a `Book` object with *only* the `ID` in it from within the Book class. No other data would be entered into it. Basically the following:

```
public boolean hasBook(int i) {
    Book b = new Book(i);
    return hasBook(b);
}

public boolean hasBook(Book b) {
    // .. more code here
    return this.books.contains(b);
}
```

All of a sudden, the `equals(Book b)` method no longer works. This took a VERY long time to track down without a good debugger and assuming the `Cart` class was properly tested and correct. After swaapping the `equals()` method to the following:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Book b = (Book) o;
    ... // The rest goes here   
}
```

Everything began to work again. Is there a reason the method decided not to take the Book parameter even though it clearly  **was**  a `Book` object? The only difference seemed to be it was instantiated from within the same class, and only filled with one data member. I'm very very confused. Please, shed some light?

Comment: I am aware that I violated the 'Contract' regarding overriding the equals methods by being reflective - however I needed a quick way to check if the object existed in the ArrayList without using generics.

Comment: This is a good lesson to learn about Java and equals

Answer (score 335, accepted):

In Java, the `equals()` method that is inherited from `Object` is:

```
public boolean equals(Object other);
```

In other words, the parameter must be of type `Object`. This is called *overriding*; your method `public boolean equals(Book other)` does what is called *overloading* to the `equals()` method.

The `ArrayList` uses overridden `equals()` methods to compare contents (e.g. for its `contains()` and `equals()` methods), **not** overloaded ones. In most of your code, calling the one that didn't properly override `Object`'s equals was fine, but not compatible with `ArrayList`.

So, not overriding the method correctly can cause problems.

I override equals the following everytime:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (other == null) return false;
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof MyClass)) return false;
    MyClass otherMyClass = (MyClass)other;
    ...test other properties here...
}
```

The use of the `@Override` annotation can help a ton with silly mistakes.

Use it whenever you think you are overriding a super class' or interface's method. That way, if you do it the wrong way, you will get a compile error.

Comment: This is a good argument in favour of the @Override annotation... if the OP had use @Override his compiler would have told him that he wasn't actually overriding a parent class method...

Comment: Was never aware of the @Override, thanks for that! I'd also like to add that overriding hashCode() really should have been done and may have spotted the error sooner.

Comment: Some IDEs (e.g. Eclipse) can even autogenerate equals() and hashcode() methods for you based on the class member variables.

Comment: `if (!(other instanceof MyClass))return false;` returns `false` if `MyClass` extends the other class. But it wouldn't return `false` if the other class extended `MyClass`. Shouldn't `equal` be less contradictory?

Comment: When using instanceof the previous nullcheck is redundant.

Comment: From the question **I wasn't using an IDE or debugger - just good old fashioned text editor and System.out's. Time was very limited and it was a school project.**  The points about IDEs helping with @Override highlight that using an IDE and debugger are probably even more important when time is very limited.

Comment: @Robert 's comment and @Nikel8000 's answer raise a VERY important point. Unless your class is final, you're breaking the contract on `equals()` that `o1.equals(o2)` should return true only if `o2.equals(o1)` also returns true. if `o1` is an instance of a subclass of `o2`, `o1 instanceof o2` returns true (and so does `o1.equals(o2)`), but `o2 instanceof o1` returns false, `o2.equals(o1)` returns false, and the contract is broken.

Comment: @Blueriver `o2 instanceof o1` isn't even legal syntax. The only potential issue would be if a subclass implemented `equals()` more restrictively.

Answer (score 110):

If you use eclipse just go to the top menu

> Source --> Generate equals() and
>   hashCode()

Comment: I agree! This one I never knew of before and generating it makes it less error prone

Comment: In IntelliJ you find this under Code → Generate… or control+N. :)

Comment: In Netbeans you go to the menu bar > Source (or right click) > Insert Code (or Ctrl-I), and click Generate equals()...

Answer (score 11):

Slightly off-topic to your question, but it's probably worth mentioning anyway:

[Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) has got some excellent methods you can use in overriding equals and hashcode. Check out [EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(...)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/EqualsBuilder.html#reflectionEquals(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) and [HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(...)](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html#reflectionHashCode(java.lang.Object)). Saved me plenty of headache in the past - although of course if you just want to do "equals" on ID it may not fit your circumstances.

I also agree that you should use the `@Override` annotation whenever you're overriding equals (or any other method).

Comment: If you're an eclipse user, you can also go `right click -> source -> generate hashCode() and equals()`,

Comment: Am I right that these method is executed at runtime? Won't we have performance issues in case if we traversing a big collection with items checking them for equality to some other item because of reflection?

Answer (score 5):

Another fast solution that saves boilerplate code is [Lombok EqualsAndHashCode annotation](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html). It is easy, elegant and customizable. And **does not depends on the IDE**. For example;

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"errorNumber","messageCode"}) // Will only use this fields to generate equals.
public class ErrorMessage{

    private long        errorNumber;
    private int         numberOfParameters;
    private Level       loggingLevel;
    private String      messageCode;
```

See the [options](http://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/EqualsAndHashCode.html) avaliable to customize which fields to use in the equals. Lombok is avalaible in [maven](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok). Just add it with *provided* scope:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.8</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

in Android Studio is
alt + insert ---> equals and hashCode

Example:

```
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Proveedor proveedor = (Proveedor) o;

    return getId() == proveedor.getId();

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Object obj = new Book();
obj.equals("hi");
// Oh noes! What happens now? Can't call it with a String that isn't a Book...
```

Comment: @Elazar How so? `obj` is declared as an `Object`. The point of inheritance is that you can then assign a `Book` to `obj`. After that, unless you suggest that an `Object` should not be comparable to a `String` via `equals()`, this code should be perfectly legal and return `false`.

Comment: I suggest exactly that. I believe it is pretty widely accepted.

Answer (score 0):

the `instanceOf` statement is often used in implementation of equals.

This is a popular pitfall !

The problem is that using `instanceOf` violates the rule of symmetry:

`(object1.equals(object2) == true)` **if and only if** `(object2.equals(object1))`

if the first equals is true, and object2 is an instance of a subclass of
the class where obj1 belongs to, then the second equals will return false!

if the regarded class where ob1 belongs to is declared as final, then this
problem can not arise, but in general, you should test as follows:

`this.getClass() != otherObject.getClass();` if not, return false, otherwise test
the fields to compare for equality!

Comment: See Bloch, *Effective Java,* Item 8, a large section discussing issues with overriding the `equals()` method. He recommends against using `getClass()`. The main reason is that doing so breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle for subclasses that don't affect equality.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getIdUsuario();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(@Nullable Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    TabUsuario that = (TabUsuario) obj;
    return Objects.equals(idUsuario, that.idUsuario);
}
```

My code last super.hashCode()

Answer (score -1):

recordId  is property of the  object

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Nai_record other = (Nai_record) obj;
        if (recordId == null) {
            if (other.recordId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!recordId.equals(other.recordId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```