# Java ArrayList Contain always return false although it contain the same value

Tags: java, arraylist, contain

This is my Hole Class

```
class Hole {

public  int a;
public  int b;

Hole(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

So i adding an ArrayList that contain several several hole

```
public void checkPathLoop(int x, int y) {
        //rough code

        ArrayList<Hole> leftFlowInnerHole = new ArrayList<>();


        //left holes rules
        leftFlowInnerHole.add(new Hole(0, 1));
        leftFlowInnerHole.add(new Hole(1, 5));
        leftFlowInnerHole.add(new Hole(5, 4));
        leftFlowInnerHole.add(new Hole(0, 4));
```

when i add

```
Hole userInputHole = new Hole(0,1);
System.out.print(leftFlowInnerHole.contain(userInputHole));
```

it always return false !! it suppose to return true.

Is there anything i miss ??

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to override the `equals` method herited from the `Object` class (and hence also `hashCode` to respect the contract, see [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) ) in your `Hole` class.

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (`o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)`).

Basically the default `equals` implementation is an `==` comparison between the two objects

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   return (this == obj);
}
```

Since you created two different objects, while they have the same value as attributes they're two distincts objects and hence `this == obj` returns `false`.

If you did :

```
Hole a = new Hole(0,1);
leftFlowInnerHole.add(a);
System.out.print(leftFlowInnerHole.contains(a));
```

You'll see that it outputs `true`.

Answer (score 7):

You should overide the equals method of the Hole class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

if (obj == this) {
    return true;
}

if (!(obj instanceof Hole)) {
    return false;
}

Hole other = (Hole) obj;

return a == other.a && b == other.b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`contains()` method checks the `equal()` method on Object while checking .

You have to ovveride equals method in order to make it work.

[`public boolean contains(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that **(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).**

```
Edit:
```

If you not ovveriding equals method, Then default Object equals method executes and, as per docs of Equals method

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values x and y, **this method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).**

So your `userInputHole  == leftFlowInnerHole` is always false as they are pointing to different instances.

Hence to avoid the default implementation ,you just ovveride that equals in yout class and provide your implementation.

[An efficient equals(Object o) implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569688/an-efficient-equalsobject-o-implementation?lq=1)

Comment: Isn't equals() default implementation execute in this case?

Comment: Why false (because default implementation uses == for comparison)? that is the point missing in answer.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not working*

```
   if(priceidslist.contains(extraId)){
                               //Not working 
                            }
```

*I just added this lines for checking that condition in (for -loop ),then its working fine*

```
  String gh = String.valueOf(priceidslist.get(j));
                           if(gh.equals(extraId)){
                               rw.put("extraPrice",pricelist.get(j));
                           }
```