# Contains method for Java enums

Tags: java

I have a simple enum that I am iterating through to check if it contains a specific value. Here is my code -

```
private static boolean checkCountryCode(CountryCode countryCode) {
    return Arrays.asList(CountryCodeList.values()).contains(countryCode.name());
}
```

This always returns false although the country code I am passing in the request is present in the list. In this case, I can't override equals since its a enum.

The countryCode in the method argument has the countryCode I am passing in the request. In my case, it is UA (Ukraine). The CountryCodeList is a list pre-populated with all the country codes in which our application runs. Some of them are on this page - http://countrycode.org/

Also, please note both CountryCode, and CountryCodeList are enums.

Comment: Build up a static map of names to enums and check for it in there then.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more of the surrounding code in order for people to help you.  For example, we can't see the relationship between CountryCodeList and CountryCode.  You could try using the debugger or printing some values in that method to see if that gives you the answer.

Comment: I don't understand. Why not just `contains(countryCode)`? What is `CountryCodeList`?

Comment: CountryCodeList has the list of all country codes. Just as the name of the class suggests. I debugged, and that's when I found this always returns false.

Comment: The contains method uses the equals method don't forget about that.

Comment: For where are you getting CountryCodeList?. I think that is the root cause of the problem. Do the types (contents of the list and the enum values) match?

Comment: Can you post sample values of the list, and the countyCode.name, perhaps it's a case sensitivity issue.

Comment: Done. Please let me know if you have any further questions. And nope, its not a case sensitivity issue. My case is similar to the issue posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859706/java-arraylist-contain-always-return-false-although-it-contain-the-same-value. Except in my code, I can't override equals since CountryCodeList is an enum as well.

Comment: Post the source code of both `CountryCodeList` and `CountryCode`.

Answer (score 0):

If CountryCodeList is enum, you can refactor you code to this

```
private static boolean checkCountryCode(CountryCode countryCode) {
   try{
      return  CountryCodeList.valueOf(countryCode.name()) != null;
   } catch (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException e) {
      return false;
   }
}
```