# What is the Java equivalent of .NET's IEquatable<T> Interface?

Tags: java, .net

What is the Java equivalent of .NET's IEquatable Interface?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't believe there is one - which is a pain in terms of providing hash maps etc with custom equality comparisons :(

Obviously there's `Comparable<T>` as an equivalent to `IComparable<T>` and `Comparator<T>` for `IComparer<T>`, but I don't believe there's any equivalent of `IEqualityComparer<T>` and `IEquatable<T>`.

There may be third party libraries providing the same sort of interface and maps which use them of course...

Comment: It wouldn't be that much of a stretch to create a delegating decorator which implements `Map` and your own `Equatable` (*is that even a word?*) interface though.

Comment: @Esko: Do you mean making the underlying map contain proxied keys, effectively? It's doable, but it would be ugly... and I suspect it would create issues when you tried to do weak maps etc. It would have been much nicer if it had been in there to start with.

Comment: Why not that way too. Proxying through `WeakReference` shouldn't be that much of an extra work, either. I do see your point though, C# has lots of these things readily implemented while Java likes to be the "barebones" language. I guess Google Collections may have something for this through its Predicate/Function system but I'm not sure...

Comment: @Esko: I don't believe I've seen any Google collections with the `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface equivalent, which is really what's required for the most general purpose solution. (It's easy to build a comparer based on an equatable type.)

Comment: The lack of an Equatable interface in the BCL is one of Java's many frustrating flaws - it essentially requires that you implement (or at least imply that you implement) a total order for a class even when it may not make any sense just to allow a type to be used as a key in a hashmap.

Answer (score 10):

If you are just looking for that interface to implement the [Equals(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1.equals) method, you can override the [Object.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method directly.

Comment: a good override implementation of `equals()` can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk

Answer (score 2):

The `IEquatable<T>` interface is primarily useful with generic classes that store many instances of what may be unboxed structure types; it's marginally useful with sealed types, and worse than useless with unsealed types.  There's thus really wouldn't be any point to implementing `IEquatable<T>` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

There's an equivalent type in Guava called [Equivalence<T>](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html).