# Key not found in a HashMap for a composite object

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

So, I made my own composite key in Java with 3 members

```
public class MyOwnKey{
int location;
int length;
String [] tokens;
}
```

Now I create two objects using the constructor

```
String [] tokens = "Stackoverflow is great".split("\\s+");
Object key1 = new MyOwnKey(0,0,tokens)
tokens = "Web is great".split("\\s+");
Object key2 = new MyOwnKey(0,0,tokens)
```

Now, I add the key in HashMap
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.put(key1,1);

Now, this is the problem
when I do contains key, it gives false;

```
**map.containsKey(key2) //returns false whereas it should return true.**
```

Just so that it makes sense:

```
key1.equals(key2) returns true
```

and the hashcode codes are also equal. `key1.hashCode() == key2.hashCode().`

I have implemeneted my own version of hashCode, toEquals() and toCompare().

Not sure what's the problem.

Here is the code

```
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

public class PatternGeneratorKey implements WritableComparable<Object> {


    private String [] tokens;
    int location;
    int length;

    StringBuffer _toString = null;

    public PatternGeneratorKey(){
        tokens = new String[1];
        location =0;
        length=1;
    }

    public PatternGeneratorKey(int location, int length, String [] tokens){

        this.location = location;
        this.length = length;

        this.tokens=  new String[tokens.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length;i++){
            this.tokens[i] = tokens[i];
        }

    }

    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof PatternGeneratorKey))
            return -1;
        return this.compareTo((PatternGeneratorKey) o);
    }

    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {

        out.writeInt(tokens.length);
        for(int i = 0; i<tokens.length;i++){
            out.writeUTF(tokens[i]);

        }
        out.writeInt(location);
        out.writeInt(length);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {

        int l = in.readInt();

        tokens = new String[l];
        for(int i = 0; i < l ; i++){
            tokens[i] = in.readUTF();
        }
        location = in.readInt();
        length = in.readInt();
    }

    public int compareTo(PatternGeneratorKey k) {

        if(this.tokens.length - this.length != k.tokens.length - k.length){
            return this.tokens.length - this.length -( k.tokens.length - k.length);
        }

        if(this.location != k.location){
            return this.location  - k.location;
        }

        int i = 0 , j= 0;
        for(i = 0, j=0 ; i < this.tokens.length && j < k.tokens.length;){

            if(i == this.location ){
                i = i + length;
                continue;
            }
            if( j == k.location){
                j = j + k.length;
                continue;
            }
            if(!this.tokens[i].equalsIgnoreCase(k.tokens[j])){
                return this.tokens[i].compareTo(k.tokens[j]);
            }else{
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }


        //TODO: add comparison on left out phrase
        return 0;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode=0;     
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length;){

            if(i == location ){

                i = i + length;
                continue;
            }
            hashCode += tokens[i++].hashCode();
        }

        hashCode+= location + tokens.length;
        return hashCode;
    }


    public String toString(){

        if(_toString == null){
            _toString = new StringBuffer();
            for(int k = 0; k < tokens.length ;k++){
                if(k==location){
                    _toString.append(":").append(" ");
                    k=k+length-1;
                }else{
                    _toString.append(tokens[k]).append(" ");
                }
            }
        }

        return _toString.toString();
    }

    public boolean equals(PatternGeneratorKey k) {

        if(this.tokens.length - this.length == k.tokens.length - k.length 
                && this.location == k.location){

            //assume second one is larger
            String tokens[] = k.tokens;
            int length = k.length;
            int location = k.location;

            String [] tokens1 = this.tokens;
            int length1 = this.length;
            int location1 = this.location;
            //make the local variable point to the largest of the two
            if( this.tokens.length > k.tokens.length){
                tokens = this.tokens;
                length = this.length;
                location = this.location;
                tokens1 = k.tokens;
                length1 = k.length;
                location1 = k.location;

            }

            int i = 0 , j= 0;
            for(i = 0, j=0 ; i < tokens.length;){

                if(i == location ){

                    i = i + length;
                    continue;
                }
//              if( j >= location1 && j<= location1 + length1 -1){
                if( j == location1){
                    j = j + length1;
                    continue;
                }
                if(!tokens[i++].equalsIgnoreCase(tokens1[j++])){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And, this is the code I am testing on

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;


public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String value = "gm used cars";
        // Compile all the words using regex
        String[] tokens = value.toString().split("\\s+");

        //to find pattern we need atleast two words in the query
        if(tokens.length <=1){
            return;
        }

        Map<PatternGeneratorKey,List> map = new HashMap<PatternGeneratorKey, List>();

        for(int l = 1 ; l < tokens.length; l++){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < tokens.length - (l-1); i++){
                String hit = new String(getPhrase(l, i, tokens));
                PatternGeneratorKey key1 = new PatternGeneratorKey(i, l, tokens);
                List list = null;
                for(int k = 0;k< tokens.length;k++){
                    System.out.println("i:" + i + ",l:" + l + ",tokens:" + tokens[k]);
                }
                System.out.println("hashcode:" + key1.hashCode());

                if(!map.containsKey(key1)){
                    list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    map.put(key1, list);
                }else{
                    list = (List) map.get(key1);
                }
                list.add(hit);
            }
        }
            value = "ford used cars";
            String[] tokens2= value.toString().split("\\s+");

            PatternGeneratorKey key2 = new PatternGeneratorKey(0, 1, tokens);

            //run a sliding window for length 1 to tokens length -1
            for(int l = 1 ; l < tokens2.length; l++){
                //genereate token pairs with sliding window. 
                for(int i = 0 ; i < tokens2.length - (l-1); i++){
                    //hit a single token or a + b if there are two.
                    String hit = new String(getPhrase(l, i, tokens2));
                    PatternGeneratorKey key1 = new PatternGeneratorKey(i, l, tokens2);

                    System.out.println();

                    System.out.println(key1.toString() + "|" + key2.toString() + "|"+ key1.equals(key2));
                    for(int k = 0;k< tokens2.length;k++){
                        System.out.println("i:" + i + ",l:" + l + ",tokens:" + tokens2[k]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("hashcode:" + key1.hashCode());

                    List list = null;
                    if(!map.containsKey(key1)){
                        list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        map.put(key1, list);
                    }else{
                        list = (List) map.get(key1);
                    }
                    list.add(hit);
                }
            }

            value = "ford used cars";
            tokens= value.toString().split("\\s+");


            PatternGeneratorKey key1 = new PatternGeneratorKey(0,1,tokens);


             tokens2 = "gm used cars".split("\\s+");
             key2 = new PatternGeneratorKey(0,1,tokens2);

            System.out.println(key1.equals(key2));
            System.out.println(key2.equals(key1));

            System.out.println(key1.hashCode() );
            System.out.println(key2.hashCode() );

            System.out.println(map);

    }

    private static String getPhrase(int l, int i, String[] tokens){

        StringBuffer strin = new StringBuffer();

        int index = 0;
        for(index = i ; index < i+l;index++){
            if(index < i+l-1){
                strin.append(tokens[index]).append("+");
            }
            else
            {
                strin.append(tokens[index]);

            }
        }
        return strin.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: toEquals? toCompare? hopefully that's just typos.

Comment: the problem is probably the equals and hashcode implementations.  Posting them would be very helpful.

Comment: can we see the full version of your MyOwnKey class, or atleast the part that calculates the hash code and equals etc? Also, why exactly should those 2 keys be equal?

Comment: After understand the solutions posted by members on my question, I did some more research and stumble upon this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that `equals(PatternGeneratorKey)` doesn't override `equals(Object)` (but it overloads `equals(Object)`, so that `key1.equals(key2)` returns `true` when `key1` and `key2` are variables of type `PatternGeneratorKey`!).

Since `HashMap` calls `equals(Object)` to check keys for equality, your method never gets called, so you need to implement `equals(Object)` instead.

Comment: Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk

Comment: Great catch! If you always remember to add the @Override annotation to your 'supposedly' extended methods, these issues can be caught at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in either hashCode() or equals(). Show us the code.

Wild guess: in your code key1.equals(key2) doesn't mean key2.equals(key1).

Comment: key2.equals(key1) also returns true.

Answer (score 2):

You created an *overload* for `equals(MyOwnKey)` instead of *overriding* `equals(Object)`.

Use the `@Override` annotation on `equals()` and `hashCode()`. It will catch this fairly common error at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

HashMap#containsKey overrides AbstractMap#containsKey - so there's a subtle difference in the way that the condition:

"Returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))"

is implemented.

For a subclass of AbstractMap which doesn't override containsKey() then you may well be able to get away with just implementing equals() correctly. However, for a HashMap, you need to have the implementation of hashCode() correct and satisfying the appropriate identity as well.

In any case - show us the code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually implemented equals.

public boolean equals(PatternGeneratorKey k) {

is not what HashMap uses.  It's looking for public boolean equals(**Object** obj) {}