# when I use @IdClass LinkedHashSet include duplicate items

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, linkedhashset

I have tasked to prepare a quote search screen. I have referred to an Oracle view 
to create quote model. As there is no id column in the view table, I prefer to use composite id using @IdClass annotation via quoteId.class. I override hashCode and equals method on both model.  quoteId equals & hashcode returns a combination of all fields and quote hashcode & equals simply just compare this.quoteNo field in the model.

Quote model:

```
@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17,37)
    .append(quoteNo)
    .toHashCode();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    final quoteModel other = (quoteModel ) obj;
    return new EqualsBuilder().appendSuper(super.equals(other))
            .append(quoteNo, other.quoteNo).isEquals();
}
```

And when I need unique items I was just accessing via:

```
uniqueQuoteResults = new ArrayList<Quote>(
                    new LinkedHashSet<Quote>(fullQuoteResults));
```

But when I start using idClass my linkedHashSet has all items even their quote number same. Am I missing any other implementation to proof each item uniqueness via quote no field(comparable, comparator)? If I trace uniqueQuoteResult list items values all of them has same quote number.

**Edit Note:** I have changed my way to using apache library HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder support but problem stays same. I am afraid of idClass hashcode is getting effective for linkedhashset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With following code in your model you test is this.quoteNo same instance as obj.quoteNo:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.quoteNo == ((EprocAwquoteV) obj).quoteNo;
}
```

Result is that two instances with separately constructed instance of IdClass will be considered to be not equals, if quoteNo is not same object. I guess you want to test equality of quoteNo's instead with something like:

```
this.quoteNo.equals(other.quoteNo);
```

Also there is some other problems with current implementation of equals in model (for example it can throw ClassCastException). Basic principles can be found from: [Object.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [Overriding the java equals() method quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk). 
Additionally with Hibernate it is important to remember, that you should not test are class same, but use instanceof instead (because of proxy classes). Some instructions about writing equals&hascode for entities can be found from [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode).

**EDIT:**
Your current approach does not work, because

```
 return new EqualsBuilder().appendSuper(super.equals(other))
```

boils it down to the Object.equals. If you do not have superclass with meaningful equals implementation. I am not totally sure do I understand your case right, so maybe you can take a look to the following working example and find out where is the difference:

```
public class QuoteId implements Serializable {
    private int id1;
    private int id2;

    public QuoteId() {}

    //This equals does not matter when we build LinkedHashSet
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        QuoteId other = (QuoteId) o;
        return id1 == other.id1 && id2 == other.id2;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 31 * id1 + id2;
    }
}

@Entity
@IdClass(QuoteId.class)
public class Quote {
    @Id private int id1;
    @Id private int id2;
    String value;

    public Quote() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Quote other = (Quote) o;
        return id1 == other.id1 && id2 == other.id2;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return 31 * id1 + id2;}

    //get&set for id1, id2, and value are omitted
}


tx.begin();
em.persist(new Quote(1, 1, "val"));
em.persist(new Quote(1, 2, "val"));
tx.commit();

TypedQuery<Quote> query = em.createQuery("SELECT q FROM Quote q", Quote.class);
List<Quote> twoQuotes = query.getResultList();//both

//duplicating (size=4) result for sake of test;
List<Quote> fullQuoteResults = new ArrayList<Quote>();
fullQuoteResults.addAll(twoQuotes);
fullQuoteResults.addAll(twoQuotes);

//will have same elements as in twoQuotes:
List<Quote> uniqueQuoteResults = new ArrayList<Quote>(
        new LinkedHashSet<Quote>(fullQuoteResults));
```

Comment: Hi Mikko, thank you for answer, after a while I have changed to HashCodeBuilder and EqualsBuilder from Apache library but the problem stays same. Tonight I will review project via your comments and will update my question.

Comment: You are welcome. Problem with your current version is likely: "new EqualsBuilder().appendSuper(super.equals(other)". I guess your quoteModel extends Object directly and as usual, every instance of object is different and other things you append will not even be considered.

Comment: Can be that I do not get details of your case right. Maybe you can use working example I added to the answer and find out where is the difference.