# Is using Object.equals() in Java an acceptable practise?

Tags: java, object

I've created a complex object in Java and I'm comparing it using the equals method.

Is this okay or is it preferred to give the object a name or an id and compare the objects names/ids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `equals()` method. If you want to make equality a name and/or id comparison, do it inside the `equals()` method.

It is the default way that [Java determines equality](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17).

Also, take a look at some of the answers for this question: [Overriding the java equals() method quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk)

There's a relationship between `equals()` and `hashcode()`. Both of these are used by Collections.

Answer (score 3):

The default `equals` inherited from `Object#equals()` compares references. In other words it returns true if the 2 objects are identical (same object in memory).

If you want equals to return true if 2 of your objects share the same characteristics, even if they are different objects, then you should override equals and compare these characteristics.

If you override equals, [you should also override hashcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Comment: And you should also override hashCode() so that if two objects are equal, they have the same hash code.