# Do I use list.remove correctly?

Tags: java, list, object

Assume that I know that the list SomeList contains thatObj. Does the following code remove reference to thatObj from SomeList or not?

```
SomeClass el = (SomeClass) thatObj.clone();
SomeList.remove(el);
```

Can't find through the reference if this method compares objects somehow. Intuition suggests that it should use Object.equals which returns true if references point to the same object, hence this code will not work.

If not then an additional question: how to remove from  list if don't have the reference but know all the members of the object in question?

Comment: Your intuition is exactly correct (unless you override `equals()`).

Comment: `Object.equals` does not take the references in account, it takes the `equals` implementation in account which happen to be standardly using the reference. If you override `equals` with your own meaningful implementation, you can remove objects with the same data that have different references.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where this is described accurately, 'cos Oracle docs are ambiguous about this?

Comment: @IgorTraskunov: the docs explicitly state that `equals` is used. `(o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i)))` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 1):

> Can't find through the reference if this method compares objects somehow. Intuition suggests that it should use Object.equals which returns true if references point to the same object, hence this code will not work.

Yes, you are right.

> If not then an additional question: how to remove from list if don't have the reference but know all the members of the object in question?

Two possibilities:

- override the equals method in your class, create a new instance with all known members and `call` remove passing the newly created instance as a parameter
- iterate through all the objects inside the list and remove the one that has the members equal to the values you have

Answer (score 1):

`remove` method internally uses the `equals` method to check for the object in the list. If equal returns true then it will be removed. Overriding the `equals` method will allow to remove the objects properly. For your reference here is the code of ArrayList remove method:

```
 public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
            for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        if (elementData[index] == null) {
            fastRemove(index);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
            fastRemove(index);
            return true;
        }
        }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the equals method on the class - here is the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). Also look at [Overriding the java equals() method quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk) and [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

Search the list to find the member by returning the index, then get the object and remove it. You can also remove it by the index. The code

```
SomeList.indexOf()
```

could help you to get the index of the object that override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.