# Running an overrided method of a class?

Tags: java, interface

This is an example of what I'm trying to do, this is hard to explain so this is the simplified version using pets:

```
public interface Pet {

    public String talk();
}

public class Dog implements Pet{

       public String talk()
       {
           return "Woof!";
       }
}

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Person {

    ArrayList<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

       public Person()
       {
         pets.add(new Dog()); 
       }

       public void makePetsSpeak()
       {
          for(int i=0; i < pets.size(); i++)
          {
            System.out.println(pets.get(i).talk());
          }
       }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.makePetsSpeak();
    }
}
```

When running Person.MakePetsSpeak() it returns nothing. Is what i'm doing possible or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Please post compilable code, not just random code, if you claim that you're running it.

Comment: Also, show us how you run it.

Comment: And *please* use proper naming conventions. Method names start with *lowercase* in Java.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but I was sure I set this to email on reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modified version of your code runs OK. Indeed MakePetsSpeak returns
nothing as it is declared void. But "Woof!" is printed out. So the answer
is you have no real problem here (once you fix the compilation errors).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

abstract interface Pet {
    public String Talk();
}

class Dog implements Pet {

    public String Talk() {
        return "Woof!";
    }
}

public class Person {
    List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

    public Person() {
        pets.add(new Dog());
    }

    public void MakePetsSpeak() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pets.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(pets.get(i).Talk());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.MakePetsSpeak();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. It was very hard for me to write out as the code i've written is nothing short of over complicated and would take me longer to write out than making a smaller example would :D

Answer (score 1):

An interface is always abstract. So

```
public abstract interface Pet
```

will be

```
public interface Pet
```

Abstract is used in some codes (old codes) just for compatibilty, but you don't need it anymore.

List don't have a `Count` method. Use [`size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29)

To get an item from a List you should use [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method.

You should change your

```
System.out.println(pets(i).Talk());
```

to

```
System.out.println(pets.get(i).Talk());
```

And, anyway your code remember me a C# code. Follow java rules about naming conventions.

Comment: All of your statements should be comments. You don't answer the question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I dunno, it actually fixes all the problems and provides code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis His title says he can't run the method. My answer explain why he can't

Comment: @BrianRoach If that is really the problem, we should close for `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't know that I'd call completely uncompilable code "a simple typographical error" ;)

Comment: @BrianRoach But it definitely won't help anyone else (which is the part I left out from that close text).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That we can agree on :) (And I did vote to close like 10 mins ago)

Comment: To clarify with everyone. The code above wasn't exactly what I'm trying to do. The code I have is hard to put show as there's a lot of it. Sorry for the bad syntax but the Issue is making .Talk() work for Dog not pet. I do believe that .get(i).talk() might be the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Corrected your compilation problems, and looks like it works just fine, with the expected behaviour.
Also, follow `Java` naming conventions - functions start with lower case.

Pet.java

```
public interface Pet {

    public String talk();
}
```

Dog.java

```
public class Dog implements Pet{

       public String talk()
       {
           return "Woof!";
       }
}
```

Person.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Person {

    ArrayList<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

       public Person()
       {
         pets.add(new Dog()); 
       }

       public void makePetsSpeak()
       {
          for(int i=0; i < pets.size(); i++)
          {
            System.out.println(pets.get(i).talk());
          }
       }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.makePetsSpeak();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Woof!
```

Comment: Thank you. Can this work with hashmaps as well?

Comment: I don't see the relation of this code with `hashmaps`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. That's the `Main` class. What do you mean if this can work with `hashmaps`?

Comment: Sorry but I kept pressing enter rather than shift + enter for new line

Comment: Yes, you could have something like that. Actually, a `Person` could have more than 1 `Pet`, so the `HashMap` should have a `List` of `Pet`. Also, to get the value from the key `Person`, you would have to override the `equals` method, used in the `HashMap` `get` method. Hope it helped.

Comment: is there a standard way of doing this, i.e. can you point me in the direction of a tutorial or an example of overriding the get method, no idea how to do something like this?

Comment: Override the `equals` method of `Person`, not the `get`.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk

Comment: I've had a go at the arraylist within my code but still can't get it working. I have to use definite types e.g. in the examples case I would have to give person a Dog rather than array of pets and do p.Dog.talk();. I'll keep at it there must be something I've missed