# String input until dot is entered

Tags: java

I want to make a program that keeps getting string input and only stops when "." is entered, any ideas how to make it?

I understand that I need to make a string array, but what's the length I'm gonna give it if I dont know how many strings the user will enter?

This is my first time to use this website, so excuse me for any mistakes.

Thank you.

Edit:
Here's a code that is confusing me. I keep entering dots but the for loop never breaks. Also the length is currently 10, how can I make it unlimited until the input is a dot?

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] x = new String[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {   
        x[i]=s.next();
        if(x[i]==".")
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *"I understand that I need to make a string array, but what's the length I'm gonna give it if I dont know how many strings the user will enter?"* Well, it's not at all clear to me you need an array, but the good news is that if you do, JavaScript's standard arrays don't need to have a predefined length, they can grow. (This is because they [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html) *[disclosure: that's a post on my anemic little blog]*.)

Comment: I have posted a code below, please have a look at it.

Comment: Please update your question instead of dumping the code in the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    inputs.add(s.next());
    if(inputs.get(inputs.size().equals("."))
        break;
}
```

Remember to `import` `ArrayList`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more information about `ArrayList`.
In java `==` is an operator used for comparing references. your new String won't have the same reference as "." which will be created at compilation time.

`equals()` method is used for comparing if the objects equal. In case of `String` it compares char by char to see if they are all the same. If yes, it returns true. False otherwise.

Remember to always `@Override` the `public boolean equals()` in your class. You have to decide what it means that to object of a certain class are equal and implement it. it'll be useful if you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk) topic. It's widely described there.

Comment: Avoid answering obvious duplicates like this question. Flag as dupe instead.

Comment: @Tom flagged. I've found this topic tagged as `javascript` just a moment before with js answer attached. It would be a pity if it get locked with just a javeascript answer.