# Java equals method does not work as intended

Tags: java, list, arraylist, equals

pieces instance is a List that contains class Piece. Piece object contains two instance variables that resemble coordinate int x and int y. However, when I tried these methods, the second method does not return true if the parameter piece is already inside the pieces object. I have generated an equal method on the class Piece. not sure why the second method does not work.

```
 public boolean alreadyContainsCoordinate1(Piece piece) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getLength(); i++) {
            if (pieces.get(i).getX() == piece.getX() && pieces.get(i).getY() == piece.getY()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean alreadyContainsThisCoordinate2(Piece piece) {
         for (Piece body : pieces) {
            if (body.equals(piece)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false; 
    }
```

Comment: Where's the overriden equals method that you mentioned?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding the java equals() method quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185937/overriding-the-java-equals-method-quirk)

Comment: why tags `java-8`, `list`, `ArrayList` ?

Comment: What's wrong with `pieces.contains(piece)`?

Comment: Do you really intend `equals` to mean "has the same co-ordinates as"?  That seems to me to be a counter-intuitive thing to want `equals` to mean.

Comment: Give the entire code, this **PATCH** of lines make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your second `alreadyContainsThisCoordinate2()` method is probably using the default `equals()` method for objects, which compares references, not the contents of your particular object.  You may try to override `equals` as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Piece)) {
        return false;
    }

    Piece p = (Piece)o;
    return this.getX() == p.getX() && this.getY() == p.getY();
}
```

Comment: I'm using intellij so I use the auto generate. it does create an override method like that.

Comment: @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Piece piece = (Piece) o;
        return x == piece.x &&
                y == piece.y;
    }

Comment: @randomNameGenerator Then I see no reason why your second method should be failing.  Try to make your question more reproducible so we have more to go by.